# How to check number of rows with only 0 on 3D matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to count how many rows does the user inputs that are only 0, something like:

```
Test 1
0 0 0
1 2 3
2 2 1

Test 2
1 2 3
0 0 0
0 0 0

Rows with only 0 values: 3
```

This is the code that reads the matrices:

```java
final int rows = 3, cols = 3;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Number of tests");

int n = input.nextInt();

int test[][][] = new int[n][rows][cols];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Test " + (i + 1));
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
            test[i][j][k] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of zero rows in a 3D matrix using *Streams* as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] test = {
            {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 1}},
            {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}};

    System.out.println(zeroRowsCount(test)); // 3
}
```

```java
public static long zeroRowsCount(int[][][] arr3d) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr3d)
            // the number of zero rows in each 2D array
            .mapToLong(arr2d -> zeroRowsCount(arr2d))
            // total number of zero rows
            .sum();
}
```

```java
public static long zeroRowsCount(int[][] arr2d) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr2d)
            // filter those rows that consist of zeros
            .filter(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                    // all elements are zeros
                    .allMatch(i -> i == 0))
            // the number of zero rows
            .count();
}
```